# I want to integrated google search box while user search my website in google. Like Mashable,BuzzFeed does

Tags: web

I want to integrate google search in website such way that whenever we  search in google the search box should show like below image. we have used @context and schema and somewhere I found on google block of code is:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">         
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "potentialAction": 
    {
       "@type": "SearchAction",
       "target": "http://www.WEBSITENAME.com/search?q={search_term}",
       "query-input": "required name=search_term"
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got help from here.

http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2431095/how-do-i-get-a-search-box-to-appear-in-my-site-s-search-results

Hope this will help you. Also It takes some time.